# Windows 10 shortcut run as administrator no credentials

Tags: windows, administrator, shortcuts

I am logged in as a user. I have created a cmd script to run an elevated command (eg netsh interface set interface wifi ENABLED). Each time I run it, it asks me for the administrator password, which is a pain. Is there a way to run this shortcut without being asked for the password each time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am logged in as a usert asks me for the administrator password, which is a pain. Is there a way to run this shortcut without being asked for the password each time  .... No.   You would need to try a scheduled task.  Allowing users to run as Admin without challenge is a breach of security.

Comment: OK, but the similar runas command can save the password "/savecred" - unfortunately it does not work, hence the need for a .cmd - if only it would save the password somewhere just as the runas does?

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled task that runs the command or *.cmd *.bat script with elevated privileges. Set an admin account to run the task. Make sure the task runs on demand...

Create a shortcut that points to the scheduled task ex:

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c schtasks /run /tn TaskName
```

Comment: OK it is done. We have a scheduled task which runs a command script which enables/disables the ethernet, wifi etc, and then we also have a command script that runs the scheduled task. A very roundabout way but it works!

Comment: Can you click on arrow up or mark the answer as solution?

Comment: I cannot, not enough rep

Comment: OK, I have now moved to a new PC and this scheme no longer works. In particular I cannot run the scheduled task unless I am admin or run as admin... Still Windows 10.